# Docman plugin configuration

Tags: plugins, documents, documentation, tuleap

Can someone tell me how to allow docman plugin to manage obsolescence date  ?

I saw the constant `...VALIDITY_PERMANENT` into the file `docman/include/Docman_MetadataHtml.class.php` and  `DOCMAN_Contants.php` but I can change it's value through plugin administration forms.

There's a clue there?

Is there something on installation process or is only plugin configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I beg your pardon, I finally found how to change the behavior but I want to share with you, perhaps can help some else !

The obsolescence date field is managed into the menu :
 **Documents > Admin > Manage properties**

There you find the field obsolescence date with a status. If it is declared "Unused" you can click on the field name which redirect you on the field configuration form.

If you set the obsolete date, then you can revert your choice on the specific document into the menu : 
 **Documents > Admin > Manage obsolescence date**

Voila!

Hope this can help and incite the Tuleap documentation maintainer to update it.